# Nuget Automatic Package Restore fails on command line

Tags: command-line, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have migrated my MSBuild-Integrated solution into Automatic Package Restore. It works on Visual Studio but when I try running the command

```
nuget restore Path/To/MySolution.sln
```

(I try doing that in my Package Manager console as well as in my Jenkins "Windows batch command" build step)

but in those cases I get an error **The solution file has two projects named "1_2".**

I cannot find these projects in my solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any projects in the directory that are not referenced by the solution?

Comment: Probably there is a possibility of solution file referenced inside another solution file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering before but I ended up finding out that the solution had two websites created from the local IIS and they ended with a version number that was the same. Visual Studio named the project with this end only, which made this solution with two 'projects' with the same name. I could see it by looking in the sln file. Looks like VS does not treat this edge case :-/